Can an immediate value be moved into to a memory location without loading it into a register first?
I've been learning x64 assembly lately from a book (Learn to program in Assembly, Jonathan Bartlett). The book claims, "In order to manipulate the data, we have to move it into registers first." Context: Manipulating data in the .section .data directive.
As per the book, only the following is legal.
.section .data
number: 
      .quad 0

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
      movq $100, %rax
      movq %rax, number

But when I tried directly loading immediate values into a memory location without loading them into any register first, it worked fine.
movq $100, number

Note: I'm using GAS assembler and AT&T syntax.

Your book is over-simplifying (or wrong); mov-immediate to memory is encodeable for 64-bit values that fit in a sign-extended 32-bit immediate, but not the full range of int64_t.  (Only mov-to-reg allows 64-bit immediates.)  See why we can't move a 64-bit immediate value to memory?  Essentially a duplicate, since that explains the things you can and can't do in x86 machine code, and links to some other Q&As about movq vs. movabs in AT&T syntax and how the GNU assembler handles it.

Also, feel free to name the book so future readers with the same question about it can more easily find stuff about its claims.

See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov, the mov r/mX, immX forms at the bottom, opcodes C6 and C7.

BTW, the normal way to address a variable in .data (or any other static storage) in x86-64 is with a RIP-relative addressing mode.  movq $100, number(%rip).  That's one byte shorter machine code than 32-bit absolute addressing, and works in PIE executables.  (Why does this MOVSS instruction use RIP-relative addressing? / 32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux? ).  Hopefully your book is going to get to that later.  If not, it's not teaching you the things you'll see in real-world asm.

@PeterCordes I'm not that good at assembly. Can you break it down and explain it in a simple terms.

If your book mentions the phrase "RIP-relative", and/or if code examples later in the book use addressing-modes of the form foo(%rip), keep reading, it will explain it.  RIP-relative means addressing data relative to the program-counter (with 32-bit offsets so you can address data +-2GiB away from code), instead of with 32-bit absolute address (low and high 2GiB of memory) or 64-bit absolute address (movabs: bloated code-size, x86-64 only supports loading/storing AL/AX/EAX/RAX)
